# Swift iOS - API data and cache

Tags: ios, swift, caching

my app is a blog. On each blog post page, I make a request to my server to get the relevant data. I'd also like to keep a view count each time the blog page is viewed.

I can do this on the backend when it receives a request. I'm not too sure how cache works in iOS, but my question is, if this data is cached on subsequent views, will this request still be made to the backend on each subsequent view?

Or should I explicitly make a background request in my ViewController to update the view count tally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `URLRequest` to call your API, then you can set the cachePolicy so that if your backend responds with the correct caching headers then if nothing has changed it won't reload.

You may want to re-architect your API so that you don't have to load the whole blog post every time just to update the view count.  Perhaps that should be a separate API call, which has its own caching policy (since it changes more frequently)

Comment: Thank you! So If I do not set any cache-headers from my backend, each time the view is loaded, it will make the API request to my backend?

Comment: Correct.  You can also force `URLRequest` to ignore cache-headers as well.  See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlrequestcachepolicy)